# Does quantum measurement uncertainty still apply when conjuate measurements are inferred?

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, quantum-measurements

Consider an apparatus which emits a particle at A which then travels through free space to B. I measure some aspect of that particle at A and transmit that information to B in a light beam.

Let's say I measure the position and time of emission of this particle at A with a high degree of accuracy. Because of quantum uncertainty, I have low accuracy information about its energy and momentum.

When this particle arrives at B, I can accurately measure the momentum, and energy. I know the distance between them and travel time because I have already built and measured this.

Combining the measurements, it seems I can have inferred knowledge of the position, energy, momentum, and time of the event at A.

If B is very far away from A, it seems that I can arbitrarily reduce the error in my inferred measurements, since the error is related to $\Delta t/t$, which shrinks as $\Delta t$ (measurement error) is constant and $t$ (travel time) increases.

Is there a problem with my experimental design, or does the uncertainty principle actually not apply in such cases?

Answer (score 0):

These two statements:

> Let's say I measure the position and time of emission of this particle at A with a high degree of accuracy

and

> When this particle arrives at B, I can accurately measure the momentum, and energy

are in **direct contradiction** with each other.

When you measure the position of the particle, you are *acting on its wavefunction*. In particular, you're *localizing* the wavefunction of the particle. So it's not just that you have "low accuracy information about its energy and momentum"; more accurately, **the particle's momentum is not well-determined** in the first place!

When the particle arrives at B, you can certainly measure an energy and a momentum, but your measurements will have a very high *spread*. The more accurate your position measurement is, the wider the spread there will be between measurements of momentum. If the particle is localized enough, you'll measure a wildly different value of momentum each time!

Comment: If a particle of known mass travels a known distance in a known time, it has known momentum, no? In this setup, its mass is intrinsic (plus relativistic component from known travel velocity), its travel distance was measured accurately in advance, and its travel time can be measured with a vanishing error because $\Delta t$ is constant while $t$ increases. Right?

Comment: @spraff Its travel time will differ wildly from measurement to measurement. No matter how accurately you measure time for each individual measurement, the spread _between_ measurements will be large, corresponding to the fact that the momentum, and hence the travel time, is not well-determined after you measure the position.

Comment: I disagree. I can send a coincident light pulse from A to B whose travel time is precisely known because the distance is precisely known in advance.

Comment: @spraff I thought you were trying to measure the momentum of the _particle_ when it passed by B, since you were talking about a measurement "when this particle arrives at B". Unless your particle is a photon, the travel time of the light pulse has absolutely nothing to do with the travel time of the particle. And if your particle _is_ a photon, then its travel time has absolutely nothing to do with its momentum (since light travels at the same speed $c$ regardless of the momentum of the photons).

Comment: Okay, let's just shoot a photon. I measure the positions of A and B with high precision in advance, and the momentum of the photon with high precision as it is emitted; I can infer its corresponding positions because they will be the same as the positions of A and B.

Comment: @spraff When you measure the photon's momentum, you change the photon's wavefunction. The more precisely you measure the photon's momentum at emission, the less well-defined the photon's _position_ at emission will be (since photons with very well-defined momenta are very, very spread out; in the limit of exactly-determined momentum, the photon is a plane wave covering all space). So you'll still have an intrinsic spread in the time-of-flight that you measure, and this spread gets worse as you measure momentum more precisely.